# black screen after installing Kernel 3.0

Tags: kernel

welcome,
i have install Kernel 3.0 on ubuntu 11.04 natty, but i got an black screen during login to ubuntu.
this screen appear on login screen, but i enable num-lock and type my password and hit enter (without seeing login window) to login to ubuntu.

Comment: please expand your question - why are you using kernel 3.0? What graphics card are you using?  Are you using any graphics drivers?  What is your grub boot options?

Comment: It's important to state whether you are trying the Ubuntu 3.0 kernel which is being built as part of the development work for the next Ubuntu release (Oneiric), or whether you are using the upstream kernel. If you are using the upstream kernel, where did you get it from? Did you build it yourself?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer: [Booting to no display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56702/booting-to-no-display/56716#56716) It seems that you aren't getting video display during the boot, as mentioned in the [Troubleshooting BlankScreen](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen) at Ubuntu Wiki.

Additionally, answers provided from other users in the same question may be useful for you. Check them at: [Booting to no display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56702/booting-to-no-display/56716#56716)

Good luck!